# Search through a list of computers to find a string in a file with ForEach- Powershell

Tags: powershell, for-loop, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

I am trying to find a string in the hosts files of computers in a text file. I want to check each machine in the text file for the change in the hosts file.

For security purposes, I cannot put the actual string I am searching for. I am very new to PowerShell, and I tried to do this in CMD, but I could not get the output I wanted.

```
$sys = Get-Content .\Systems.txt
$Loc = "\\$sys\c$\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts"
$SearchStr = "string"
$sel = Select-String -pattern $SearchStr -path $Loc


ForEach ($System in $sys) {
    If ($sel -eq $null)
    {
        write-host $sys NotFound
    }
        Else 
    {
        write-host $sys Found
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You weren't too far off, you just needed to re-think your ForEach loop a little. Move your `$Loc =` line within the loop so that it updates for each system, then skip the `$sel =` line and just put that in your `If` check and you're all set:

```
$sys = Get-Content .\Systems.txt
$SearchStr = "string"

ForEach ($System in $sys) {
    $Loc = "\\$system\c`$\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts"
    If (Select-String -pattern $SearchStr -path $Loc -Quiet)
    {
        write-host "$system Found"
    }
        Else 
    {
        write-host "$system Not Found"
    } 
}
```

I also escaped the dollar sign in the path for `c$`. I don't think it's needed in this case, but it's good practice in general when using dollar signs that you want to actually be used as such in strings like that.

Comment: I tested the changes you made, but it still doesn't work correctly. I am not sure why, but I am getting an error saying the path could not be connected to. I know the machines are online, because I am running a ping sweep on all of them, first. This script makes total sense, so there should be no reason it doesn't work.

Comment: It works for me using a search string of "127.0.0.1" and finds it on both systems I tried it on. Do you have admin rights on the computers you are trying to connect to? You usually need local admin rights to be able to connect to the c$ administrative share.

Comment: Yes, we have admin rights on all the machines. Here's the weird thing. When I was doing the same thing in CMD, I was getting almost the same error. I used 'psexec -sh', and only then was I able to find the string; I just didn't get the output I needed. Tomorrow, I'm going to modify this a bit to use psexec. Thanks for the update.

Comment: So, this ended up working without psexec. The problem ended up being user error on my part.